# Session array display only one result

Tags: php, session

Hello i receive by $_POST a user_name and a user_id.

I want to get something like this in $_SESSION :

```
(id) - (user_name)
5 - John
6- Paul 


<?php
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

       $_SESSION['test'] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);

    foreach( $_SESSION['test'] as $key => $value )
    {
          echo $key;
          echo $value;
    }
?>
```

Only John and his id is displayed. I mean Paul and his id is not showing. Why ?

---

i have a js script ,

```
$.ajax({
                    url : "ajax_chat.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: 'action='+action+'&user_id='+user_id,
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                    }
                });
```

When someone click on a user i want a session create for each id which will be send to my php file.

ajax_chat.php

```
if ($action == "ChangeSessionValueUser")
{ 
   $_SESSION['test'] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);
}
```

in index.php

```
<?php
foreach( $_SESSION['test'] as $key => $value )
{
      echo $key;
      echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: post result of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: For each click in JS i want to create a SESSION . So for user_id , it's only one value by one value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you are doing. But if you are getting only **one** `user_id` and **one** `user_name` per POST  request, then there are a few things that you'll need to do.

1. You are not actually creating a session.

You'll need to add `session_start()` to either activate, or reactivate a session here's an simple resource: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

1. with the line `$_SESSION['test'] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);`
   You will overwrite the `$_SESSION['test']` variable every time. So you'll need to append that new array to the end of 'test' like this `$_SESSION['test'][] = array(...)` (if I'm understanding what you want to do)

So your code should look something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $_SESSION['test'][] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'user_name' => $user_name);

    foreach( $_SESSION['test'] as $key => $value )
    {
          echo $key;
          echo $value;
    }
?>
```

This should add a user_id and user_name pair each time it is given one to the $_SESSION global under the "test" key.

Answer (score 1):

You did not understand arrays correctly. Take simpler code without sessions:

```
$test = array('user_id' => 5, 'user_name' => 'john');
$test = array('user_id' => 6, 'user_name' => 'paul');

print_r($test);
// this only prints paul, since you've overwritten the variable.

// You want an array of arrays instead, so
$test = array();
$test[] = array('user_id' => 5, 'user_name' => 'john');
$test[] = array('user_id' => 6, 'user_name' => 'paul');
print_r($test);
// this prints out both

// If you want to loop, you must change it a little bit
foreach ($test as $value) {
   echo 'User ' . $value['user_name'] . ' with user id ' . $value['id'];
}
// if you do echo($value); this yields "Array"
// since you have an array in an array.
```

To init the array in the session only once, you can use something like this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
  $_SESSION['test'] = array();
}
// then you can push in additional users on all pages like
$_SESSION['test'][] = array('id' => 7, 'user_name' => 'test');

// and output all with
foreach ($_SESSION['test'] as $value) {
  echo 'User ' . $value['user_name'] . ' with user id ' . $value['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a single value from POST. You need to have array names for each input field like:

```
<input type="text" name="user_id[]" />
<input type="text" name="user_name[]" />
```

Then when you receive these values, put them in session one by one:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = array();
foreach ($_POST['user_id'] as $i => $id) {
    $_SESSION['test'][] = array($id => $_POST['user_name'][$i]);
}
```